# How to return the value and name of a variable in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a macro to return a variable's name and value in common lisp. How do I return the name and value of a variable in a LISP macro?

So something like

(RETURNVAL (x))

would return

x has value 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defmacro returnval (x)
  `(format t "~a has value ~a." ',x ,x))
```

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *forty-two* 42)
*FORTY-TWO*
CL-USER> (returnval *forty-two*)
*FORTY-TWO* has value 42.
NIL
CL-USER> (let ((x 5))
           (returnval x))
X has value 5.
NIL
```

If you really want that extra set of parens around the form, you can do that, too:

```
(defmacro returnval ((x))
  `(format t "~a has value ~a." ',x ,x))
```

```
CL-USER> (returnval (*forty-two*))
*FORTY-TWO* has value 42.
NIL
CL-USER> (let ((x 5))
           (returnval (x)))
X has value 5.
NIL
```

Comment: Appreciated. I was very close, was just missing the ` before the format.

Comment: @zinkpro45 Yup, defmacro is pretty much like defun;  you just need it to *return* the source form.  You could also return `(list 'format t "~a has value ~a." (list 'quote x) x)`.  There's nothing particularly special about `\``, it's just convenience.